# How to Tee udp packets onto a different host

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I would like to clone incoming UDP packets onto a different host, I found a way to do it [Here](http://www.bjou.de/blog/2008/05/howto-copyteeclone-network-traffic-using-iptables)  but I could not build xtables-addons on centos 5.3 .

Is there any other way to tee upd packets?

Comment: I'm not clear. Do you want to actually "tee" them or do you just redirect them to another host?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.bjou.de/blog/2008/05/howto-copyteeclone-network-traffic-using-iptables/

or http://www.netfilter.org/projects/patch-o-matic/pom-external.html

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p udp --dport 7 -j ROUTE --gw 1.2.3.4 --tee
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -p udp --sport 7 -j ROUTE --gw 1.2.3.4 --tee
```

Answer (score 5):

We're using a 3.2.0 kernel on an Ubuntu 12.04, and this iptables rule did the trick (no need to patch!):

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING  -p udp --dport 60000 -j TEE --gateway 172.16.3.12
```

This will copy the incoming packets to UDP port 60000 to the IP set in `--gateway`. Take in account that the gateway should be in the same network, if don't , the rule won't work unless you do something similar in the router between networks.

I wonder if there's a way to traverse this network flow to another network, maybe NATing, but we haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I just found [samplicator](https://github.com/sleinen/samplicator) which also seems to do this.

Comment: Careful with posting this link multiple times, it is setting off the spam filter alerts.