# iptables + TEE doesn't work correctly

Tags: iptables, port, mirroring, tee

On my server, I want to duplicate all the traffic to an other host.  I use iptables with TEE module:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway IP_SERVER2
```

I check the rule: `iptables -t mangle -L`

=> The rule is here but it doesn't work... The other server receive nothing.

When I do a tcpdump: `tcpdump dst IP_SERVER2`
=> 0 packets received by filter

I tried to enable `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects`, and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects`.  I changed to 1 the `net.ipv4.ip_forward` option in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, it still doesn't work.

Have you got an idea what's wrong?

Comment: would this help? http://serverfault.com/questions/179968/how-to-tee-udp-packets-onto-a-different-host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP_SERVER2 needs to be on your local network according to iptables manpages.

Comment: Really? Ok I understand better now...

Comment: Have you an idea how to duplicate packets on another network?

Comment: I am not sure why iptables has such a limitation, but the only way I can think of is to log the packets (probably just tcpdump - see `-G` option) and ship them in files to your external network.

Comment: I've done a vpn connection between the two servers (in order to be in the same private network) and now the duplication works great.
Thanks you.