# Snort IDS on HAproxy with encrypted traffic

Tags: haproxy, snort

Using HAproxy, can I direct traffic to a backend server from all the other backend servers in a pool? From a networking standpoint, it would be comparable to mirroring all ports on a switch to one port for inspection. This way I could pass all traffic unecrypted to a loopback address and inspect it with SNORT.

Currently we encrypt all traffic into our HAproxy nodes and send that traffic encrypted to our webservers. We have an out of band IDS, however since it only has our cert to decrypt traffic, we can't implement perfect forward secrecy or diffie-helman ciphers on haproxy.

I've read guides that allow you to do this with an F5, however that's not an option for us.

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

HAProxy can't do it by itself, but if you used a set of fairly simple `frontend/listen` declerations, you could use the `iptables` `TEE` target (see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/629768/266218) for usage), it should be fairly simple.

For a system where the server's "public" IP is 10.10.10.10, who's backends are 192.168.1.11 and 192.168.1.12 and who's IDS is 172.16.172.10 the HAProxy configuration would look something like this:

```
listen IN
  mode tcp
  bind 10.10.10.10:443
  <other HAProxy options/directives here>
  server hap-intermediary 127.1.1.1:443

frontend INTERMEDIARY
   mode http
   bind 127.1.1.1:443 ssl crt /path/to/cert.pem
  <other HAProxy options/directives here>
  <backend selection logic, if needed>

  default_backend SERVERS

backend SERVERS
  <other HAProxy options/directives here>
  server server1 192.168.1.11:443 check check-ssl ssl
  server server2 192.168.1.12:443 check check-ssl ssl
```

This basically just passes all the traffic from `IN` to `INTERMEDIARY` in whatever shape it entered the server, and then `INTERMEDIARY` decrypts the requests and make whatever choices you want.

You'd then need to setup `iptables` rules that looks like this:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 127.1.1.1 -j TEE --gateway 172.16.172.10
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 127.1.1.1 -j TEE --gateway 172.16.172.10
```

Of course, this assumes all routes and networks are setup, but it should work.

I suppose you could just do away with all the HAProxy stuff and setup some `iptables` rules to match your backend hosts and `TEE` that traffic right to your IDS.

```
# Server 1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.11 -j TEE --gateway 172.16.172.10
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.11 -j TEE --gateway 172.16.172.10
# Server 2
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.12 -j TEE --gateway 172.16.172.10
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.12 -j TEE --gateway 172.16.172.10
```

Comment: Brilliant! I figured I'd have to do some iptables acrobatics in between receiving the traffic and forwarding to the backend. I'll throw this into my lab and see how it works. Thanks for the help!