# How to properly clone packets with tee?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, routing

Trying to understand the `TEE` module of iptables.
Intend is trying to clone and send the same packet to 2 IPs

Tried the following

```
iptables -A INPUT -P tcp --dport 2003 -j TEE --gateway IP1
iptables -A INPUT -P tcp --dport 2003 -j TEE --gateway IP2
```

Does this `tee` the traffic to both gateways or only the 1st rule?
running the command `iptables -L -v` shows the rules and packets getting counted against the rule.

Also saw commands with -t mangle like

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -P tcp --dport 2003 -j TEE --gateway IP1
```

Running the command `iptables -L` doesn't show prerouting values but I can see it in `iptables -S`

In any of the cases, this didn't seem like it was forwarding the packets to the said IP1 (on the same network). Running a TCP dump on the macing with IP1 could not show any data coming in.

Also any nice article on understanding IPTABLES for Dummies ...Official docs well went above my head :/

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/179968/how-to-tee-udp-packets-onto-a-different-host take a look here

Comment: Regarding iptables documentation, https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/iptables is quite decent, and [this linked picture](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/images/tables_traverse.jpg) gives a very nice overview of tables and chains ([this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) linked from wikipedia is sort of the same thing but in more detail, but it is much less clear).